# Direction of rotation in matlab/simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a general question. In Simulink, say you have identified an axis for a revolute joint (x,y,z):(1,0,0) and you plot the angle. Is the normal convention the right hand rule? In this case positive angle would mean anti-clockwise rotation around the given axis. Is there a way to verify what sign convention is used in matlab/simulink?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more details? The question as it stands doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: thanks for the reply...I'll try to explain...in simulink using simscape toolbox multi-body dynamics can be simulated. Simscape allows constraints in the form of revolute joint , prismatic joint, etc. Say I have a revolute joint and I chose the +ve x-axis as its axis of rotation. Since its a revolute joint I can also measure angle the body rotates under the revolute constraint. Now I wanna know if the angle measured in the anticlockwise direction is positive or clockwise. Generally the right hand rule is followed (or cork screw if you prefer to call it that)...how do I ensure what matlab uses?

Comment: If you are using a provided function to find the angle, it should be in the documentation. If not, look in the source code. If you are finding the angle yourself, it is up to you what the convention is.